# Sorting php array in Redis

Tags: php, redis

I Have an array of Objects (result of mysql Query)

```
    array(28) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["member_id"]=>
    string(5) "40105"
    ["last_login"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-18 06:04:06"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["member_id"]=>
    string(5) "51758"
    ["last_login"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-21 09:29:11"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["member_id"]=>
    string(5) "52682"
    ["last_login"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-21 08:27:00"
  }
```

What is the best datatype to sort it in redis ? I need to search and add an object into this result?

shall I use SET or LIST ?

Comment: The answer to your question really depends on what you want to do with the data (after storing it). Put differently, with some NoSQL databases - and definitely with Redis - you need to store your data in a manner that makes sense when you want to fetch it.

Comment: I need to store list of members id in cache so i can search in that member id. and i want to add a member into this list

Comment: @ItamarHaber and Why to use NoSQL , I am already using MongoDB

Comment: Re. NoSQL - you mentioned Redis so I assumed your question was about it and wanted to highlight this notable difference between NoSQL and SQL.

Comment: Re data type - based on your input, it looks like you should use a hash. You can HSET logins <member-id> <last-login> and then do HGET logins <member-id> with Big-Oh(1) complexity.